# How would I use Dask to perform parallel operations on slices of NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, parallel-processing, dask

I have a numpy array of coordinates of size n_slice x 2048 x 3, where n_slice is in the tens of thousands.  I want to apply the following operation on each 2048 x 3 slice separately

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

# load coor from a binary xyz file, dcd format

n_slice, n_coor, _ = coor.shape
r = np.arange(n_coor)
dist = np.zeros([n_slice, n_coor, n_coor])

# this loop is what I want to parallelize, each slice is completely independent
for i in xrange(n_slice): 
    dist[i, r[:, None] < r] = pdist(coor[i])
```

I tried using Dask by making `coor` a `dask.array`,

```
import dask.array as da
dcoor = da.from_array(coor, chunks=(1, 2048, 3))
```

but simply replacing `coor` by `dcoor` will not expose the parallelism.  I could see setting up parallel threads to run for each slice but how do I leverage Dask to handle the parallelism?

Here is the parallel implementation using `concurrent.futures`

```
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing

n_cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def get_dist(coor, dist, r):
    dist[r[:, None] < r] = pdist(coor)

# load coor from a binary xyz file, dcd format

n_slice, n_coor, _ = coor.shape
r = np.arange(n_coor)
dist = np.zeros([n_slice, n_coor, n_coor])

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_cpu) as executor:
    for i in xrange(n_slice):
        executor.submit(get_dist, cool[i], dist[i], r)
```

It is possible this problem is not well suited to Dask since there are no inter-chunk computations.

Comment: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html#configuring-the-schedulers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `map_blocks`

The [map_blocks](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.core.map_blocks) method may be helpful:

```
dcoor.map_blocks(pdist)
```

#### Uneven arrays

It looks like you're doing a bit of fancy slicing to insert particular values into particular locations of an output array.  This will probably be awkward to do with dask.arrays.  Instead, I recommend making a function that produces a numpy array

```
def myfunc(chunk):
    values = pdist(chunk[0, :, :])
    output = np.zeroes((2048, 2048))
    r = np.arange(2048)
    output[r[:, None] < r] = values
    return output

dcoor.map_blocks(myfunc)
```

#### `delayed`

Worst case scenario you can always use [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html)

```
from dask import delayed, compute
coor2 = delayed(coor)
slices = [coor2[i] for i in range(coor.shape[0])]
slices2 = [delayed(pdist)(slice) for slice in slices]
results = compute(*slices2)
```

Comment: The output of `pdist` is an array of the distances between each pair of coordinates in the slice.  For my example the result from each slice has dimensions `(2048 * 2047 / 2,)`. These arrays are actually sufficient.  I think this answer provides a good start though I think `map_blocks` is trying to execute `pdist` as if I passed in the entire 3D array. I only want it to calculate on the 2D slices, which I made into chunks; there should be no cross-chunk calculations.

Comment: It calls pdist on each `(1, 2048, 3)` sized chunk.  I would wrap your pdist function in something that takes out the first dimension and then returns the full square matrix.  Edited my answer above.